# Css Selector of page for selenium

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have the following content

```
<div class="startpack">
<div class="test-class">
    <div id="login">
        <div id="frag">
            <h3>blah blah blah</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="testfrag">
            <form class="loginform">
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="log in" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="real-class">
    <div id="login">
        <div id="frag">
            <h3>blah blah blah</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="testfrag">
            <form class="loginform">
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="log in" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="noshow-class">
    <div id="login">
        <div id="frag">
            <h3>blah blah blah</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="testfrag">
            <form class="loginform">
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="log in" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</div>
```

Now if I want my selenium code to click on the submit button inside the `<div class="real-class">` what do I use for cssSelector?

I tried

```
driver.findElementBycssSelector(".startpack>#real-class>input[class=\"button\"]").click()
```

But that didn't work. I want to make it generalized as much as possible without doing div[0] or div[1] etc.. So that if my DOM structure changes  in the future I really don't have to worry about modifying the locator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used the id selector `#` on *real-class* but actually you only have an element with the class name `.real-class`.

You can change your HTML to match this selector or just use the class selector instead `.startpack>.real-class input[class="button"]`

You also have used the direct child combinator `>` in a bad way. (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)

`#real-class>input.button` would only be true, when your html would look like this:

```
<div id="real-class">
  <input class="button" value="test" type="submit" />
</div>
```

In your example the button is not a direct child of *real-class*

Comment: That makes sense. So if I do
driver.findElementBycssSelector(".startpack>.real-class input[class=\"button\"]").click();

Will that work?

Comment: uhhh i just noticed. You shoud do this: `.startpack>.real-class input.button` I did not notice you were selecting the class there. Normaly you use this to indetify the type attribute.

Comment: It worked dude. Thanks a lot :) I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: it's taking a little bit of time to find the element and click. I think it's due to the huge DOM structure. But If I use a Xpath it's really fast unfortunately maintenance might be a difficult factor